# Сайт недоступен после дня работы на TomCat 8 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

Стоит `Ubuntu 16.04`. Поставил `TomCat 8`, залил сайт - работает. После, почти, 24 часов работы сайт становится недоступным. При этом сама хостинг машина работает и сам tomcat на ней тоже - проверял командой `sudo service tomcat status`. Почему так происходит? Помогает перезагрузка машины или самого `tomcat`-а. Подскажите, в чём проблема?

Спасибо.

Comment: А логи приложения проверяли? Возможно, в случае какой-либо БД могли автоматически закрыться все соединения, если не было обращений к БД долгое время.

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy вот что в логах: http://pastebin.com/HeJEH9GF. 
Штука в том что если соединения с бд нет то оно создаётся, тобишь проект выполняет к ней подключение.

Comment: когда подобная ситуация снова повторится, проверьте доступность вашего сервера приложения путем проверки открытых портов,например telnet <имя_сервера> <номер_порта> и сообщите нам результат

Comment: @Tsyklop в логах же написано прямо "No operations allowed after connection closed." И оно автоматически не создается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в логах написано, что соединения к MySQL все закрыты. Они не пересоздаются, а весят в пуле соединений закрытыми, поэтому возникает ошибка: "No operations allowed after connection closed.".

Добавьте к настройкам соединения с базой данных следующий параметр `autoReconnect=true`. Например, таким образом:

```
mysql://db_user:db_user@localhost/mydb?autoReconnect=true
```

Comment: `autoReconnect=true` - не надёжное решение. Лучше использовать пул соединений с автоматической проверкой соединения перед взятием из пула и с периодическим автоматическим обновлением (переподключением) соединений.

Comment: @Roman Какой-нибудь стандартный пул из Spring Framework обеспечивает такую функциональность?

Comment: В spring есть только тестовые реализации, они не подойдут. Мой личный выбор - HikariCP.

Answer (score 0):

У MySql по умолчанию таймаут на соединение составляет 8 часов (28800/60/60) согласно [документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout). По истечению 8 часов после последнего запроса к БД, соединение с ней разрывается. Для предотвращения разрыва соединения можете увеличить параметр `wait_timeout` в настройках БД на более высокое значение, чем 8 часов.

Comment: Этим вы только отдалите неизбежное. Да и не во всех случаях есть доступ к настройкам БД.

Comment: @Roman может быть и отдаляю, но тем не менее автор вопроса теперь знает почему возникает эта ошибка, как он и спрашивал. Правильный вариант использовать пул соединений, как Вы и написали, с этим я согласен.