# Исправить ошибку JDBC The last packet successfully received from the server was

Tags: java, jdbc

Помогите пожалуйста. Со временем JDBC выдаёт мне такое вот:

```
The last packet successfully received from the server was 33,107,343 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2 milliseconds ago.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3556)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3456)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3897)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
        at de.sniff.database.dbUser.UserExist(dbUser.java:145)
        at de.sniff.filters.IndexFilter.doFilter(IndexFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1504)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1460)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3008)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3466)
        ... 27 more
```

как починить это?

Comment: Что-то разорвало соединение с сервером без уведомления клиента. Это может быть как сам сервер, так и любое сетевое оборудование между клиентом и сервером. А также причиной могут быть сбои сети.

Comment: Вы уже задавали похожий вопрос,
 попробуйте [это решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602471/218319) снова.

Comment: @MrFylypenko это и так есть.